# get first item in array of Jade Template

Tags: pug

I am using express.js with jade. I have a problem in jade template.

my mogodb data is like following

```
{ _id: 5040465ce0afabce2b000003,
    address: 'Sample',
    fax: [ '22 212', '34 138' ],
    Branch: true,
    pic: [ 'photo1.png' ,'photo2.png'],
    tel: [ '22 980', '22 439' ],
    lat: 29.674292,
    Name: 'Branch 1',
    ATM: false,
    long: 98.210881 },
{ _id: 5040465ce0afabce2b000003,
    address: 'Loikaw.',
    fax: [  ],
    Branch: true,
    pic: [  ],
    tel: [],
    lat: 20.674292,
    Name: 'Loikaw Branch',
    ATM: false,
    long: 98.210881 },
```

from my jade template

```
- obj.forEach(function(item){
                tr
                    td 
                        img(src="/upload/#{item.pic}",width=200)
                    td #{item.Name}
                    td #{item.address}
                    td #{item.ATM}
                    td #{item.Branch}
                    td #{item.lat}
                    td #{item.long}
```

How can I use first array of `pic array` ?

I checked on doc, https://github.com/visionmedia/jade , it didn't include about array. They only show with Iteration and array.

If there is no pic, I want to show other pic instead.

Is there possible done in Jade template or I need to do at js side ?

Comment: Did you try `img(src="/upload/#{item.pic[0]}",width=200)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- obj.forEach(function(item){
                tr
                    td 
                        - if (item.pic[0] == undefined)
                            img(src="/images/nopic.png",width=200)
                        - else
                            img(src="/upload/#{item.pic[0]}",width=200)
```

Thank @Ray Toal